whenever i click the save button in the add item page it keeps returning an error table items has no column named IsSold
#more code above
# Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1962, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mawah\OneDrive\123.py", line 470, in save_data
    self.db.insert_item(item, size_numeric, size, year, price, condition)
  File "C:\Users\Mawah\OneDrive\123.py", line 300, in insert_item
    self.cur.execute('''INSERT INTO items (Item, SizeNumeric, Size, Year, Price, Condition, IsSold)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table items has no column named IsSold

....
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("items.db")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.create_table()

    def create_table(self):
        # Check if the table already exists
        self.cur.execute('''SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='items' ''')
        if self.cur.fetchone()[0] == 0:
            # Table doesn't exist, create it along with the IsSold column
            self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
                                ItemId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                Item TEXT,
                                SizeNumeric TEXT,
                                Size TEXT,
                                Year TEXT,
                                Price REAL,
                                Condition TEXT,
                                IsSold INTEGER )''')
            self.conn.commit()
       

    def insert_item(self, item, size_numeric, size, year, price, condition):
        # SQL query to insert an item into the table
        self.cur.execute('''INSERT INTO items (Item, SizeNumeric, Size, Year, Price, Condition, IsSold) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (item, size_numeric, size, year, price, condition, 0))
        self.conn.commit()  


    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()

class Add_Item:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry('600x600')
        master.title("Add Item")
        master.configure(bg="#A7C7E7")

        self.lblItem = tk.Label(master, text="Item", width=20, font=("Cambria", 10), bg="#A7C7E7")
        self.lblItem.place(x=80, y=130)
        self.ddlItem = ttk.Combobox(master, values=["Tie", "Blazer", "Trousers", "Polos", "Jumpers"], state="readonly")
        self.ddlItem.place(x=240, y=130)
        self.ddlItem.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.show_fields)

        # Initialize all fields
        self.lblYear = tk.Label(master, text="Year", width=20, font=("Cambria", 10), bg="#A7C7E7")
        self.ddlYear = ttk.Combobox(master, values=["yr7", "yr8", "yr9", "yr10", "yr11"], state="readonly")

        self.lblSizeNumeric = tk.Label(master, text="Size (Numeric)", width=20, font=("Cambria", 10), bg="#A7C7E7")
        self.ddlSizeNumeric = ttk.Combobox(master, values=["11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"], state="readonly")

        self.lblSize = tk.Label(master, text="Size", width=20, font=("Cambria", 10), bg="#A7C7E7")
        self.ddlSize = ttk.Combobox(master, values=["S", "M", "L", "XL"], state="readonly")

        self.lblCondition = tk.Label(master, text="Condition", width=20, font=("Cambria", 10), bg="#A7C7E7")
        self.ddlCondition = ttk.Combobox(master, values=["Good", "Bad"], state="readonly")

        self.lblPrice = tk.Label(master, text="Price", width=20, font=("Cambria", 10), bg="#A7C7E7")
        self.entPrice = tk.Entry(master)

        self.btnGoBack = tk.Button(master, text="\u2190", font=("Cambria", 20), bg="#A7C7E7", fg="black", command=self.go_back)
        self.btnGoBack.place(x=20, y=20)

        # added btnSave button
        self.btnSave = tk.Button(master, text="Save", font=("Cambria", 17), bg="#A7C7E7", fg="black", command=self.save_data)
        self.btnSave.place(x=250, y=280)  # Adjust position as needed

        self.db = Database()  # Create an instance of the Database class

        # Initially hide all fields
        self.hide_all_fields()

    def show_fields(self, event=None):
        selected_item = self.ddlItem.get()
        self.hide_all_fields()  # Hide all fields first
        if selected_item == "Tie":
            self.show_tie_fields()
        elif selected_item == "Blazer":
            self.show_blazer_fields()
        elif selected_item == "Trousers":
            self.show_trousers_fields()
        elif selected_item == "Polos":
            self.show_polos_fields()
        elif selected_item == "Jumpers":
            self.show_jumpers_fields()

    def show_tie_fields(self):
        # Show Tie related fields
        self.lblYear.place(x=80, y=160)
        self.ddlYear.place(x=240, y=160)
        self.lblCondition.place(x=80, y=190)
        self.ddlCondition.place(x=240, y=190)
        self.lblPrice.place(x=80, y=220)
        self.entPrice.place(x=240, y=220)

    def show_blazer_fields(self):
        # Show Blazer related fields
        self.lblSize.place(x=80, y=160)
        self.ddlSize.place(x=240, y=160)
        self.lblCondition.place(x=80, y=190)
        self.ddlCondition.place(x=240, y=190)
        self.lblPrice.place(x=80, y=220)
        self.entPrice.place(x=240, y=220)

    def show_trousers_fields(self):
        # Show Trousers related fields
        self.lblSizeNumeric.place(x=80, y=160)
        self.ddlSizeNumeric.place(x=240, y=160)
        self.lblCondition.place(x=80, y=190)
        self.ddlCondition.place(x=240, y=190)
        self.lblPrice.place(x=80, y=220)
        self.entPrice.place(x=240, y=220)

    def show_polos_fields(self):
        # Show Polos related fields
        self.lblSize.place(x=80, y=160)
        self.ddlSize.place(x=240, y=160)
        self.lblCondition.place(x=80, y=190)
        self.ddlCondition.place(x=240, y=190)
        self.lblPrice.place(x=80, y=220)
        self.entPrice.place(x=240, y=220)

    def show_jumpers_fields(self):
        # Show Jumpers related fields
        self.lblSize.place(x=80, y=160)
        self.ddlSize.place(x=240, y=160)
        self.lblCondition.place(x=80, y=190)
        self.ddlCondition.place(x=240, y=190)
        self.lblPrice.place(x=80, y=220)
        self.entPrice.place(x=240, y=220)

    def hide_all_fields(self):
        # Hide all fields
        self.lblYear.place_forget()
        self.ddlYear.place_forget()
        self.lblSizeNumeric.place_forget
        self.ddlSizeNumeric.place_forget()
        self.lblSize.place_forget()
        self.ddlSize.place_forget()
        self.lblCondition.place_forget()
        self.ddlCondition.place_forget()
        self.lblPrice.place_forget()
        self.entPrice.place_forget()

        self.ddlSizeNumeric.place_forget()
        self.lblSize.place_forget()
        self.ddlSize.place_forget()
        self.lblCondition.place_forget()
        self.ddlCondition.place_forget()
        self.lblPrice.place_forget()
        self.entPrice.place_forget()

    def go_back(self):
        self.db.close()# Close the database connection
        self.master.destroy()  # Close the current window when "Go Back" button is clicked 

    def save_data(self):#this is the block of code that the syntax error occurs
        # Fetching values from the widgets
        item = self.ddlItem.get()
        year = self.ddlYear.get()
        size_numeric = self.ddlSizeNumeric.get()
        size = self.ddlSize.get()
        condition = self.ddlCondition.get()
        price = self.entPrice.get()

        # Check if any of the required fields are empty based on the selected item
        if item == "Tie" and not all([year, condition, price]):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Data invalid: missing field")
            return
        elif item == "Blazer" and not all([size, condition, price]):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Data invalid: missing field")
            return
        elif item == "Trousers" and not all([size_numeric, condition, price]):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Data invalid: missing field")
            return
        elif item == "Polos" and not all([size, condition, price]):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Data invalid: missing field")
            return
        elif item == "Jumpers" and not all([size, condition, price]):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Data invalid: missing field")
            return

        # Check if price is a valid float and below or equal to £30.00
        try:
            price_float = float(price)
            if price_float > 30.00:
                raise ValueError("Price is above the limit (£30.00)")
        except ValueError as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            messagebox.showerror("Error", error_message + "\nPlease enter a valid price")
            return

        # Insert data into the database
        self.db.insert_item(item, size_numeric, size, year, price, condition)

        # Close the current window
        self.master.destroy()



   

class BuyItemPage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Buy Item")
        master.configure(bg="#A7C7E7")

        # Set the initial size of the window
        master.geometry("600x600")

        # Create a Treeview widget
        self.create_treeview()

        # Create a search entry field and button
        self.create_search_widgets()

        # Fetch items from the database and insert them into the Treeview
        self.populate_treeview()

        # Add a Back button
        self.create_back_button()

    def create_back_button(self):
        # Create a Back button to return to the original page
        self.back_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Back to Main menu", font=("Cambria", 12), bg="#A7C7E7", fg="white", command=self.back_to_categories)
        self.back_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=10)

    def back_to_categories(self):
        # Destroy the current window and return to the main page
        self.master.destroy()

    # Other methods remain the same...


    def create_treeview(self):
        # Create a Treeview widget
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.master)

        # Add columns
        self.treeview['columns'] = ('Item ID', 'Item', 'SizeNumeric', 'Size', 'Year', 'Price', 'Condition', 'Sold')

        # Define column headings
        self.treeview.heading('Item ID', text='Item ID', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('Item', text='Item', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('SizeNumeric', text='SizeNumeric', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('Size', text='Size', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('Year', text='Year', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('Price', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('Condition', text='Condition', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.treeview.heading('Sold', text='Sold', anchor=tk.CENTER)

        # Pack the Treeview
        self.treeview.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # Bind double click event to the Treeview
        self.treeview.bind("<Double-1>", self.on_item_double_click)

    def create_search_widgets(self):
        # Create search entry field and button
        self.search_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.search_var, font=("Cambria", 12))
        self.search_entry.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.X)
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Search", font=("Cambria", 12), bg="#A7C7E7", fg="white", command=self.search_items)
        self.search_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=1)

    def populate_treeview(self):
        # Connect to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect("items.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Fetch non-empty categories from the database
        cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(Item) FROM items WHERE Item IS NOT NULL AND Item != ''")
        categories = cursor.fetchall()

        # Clear existing items from the Treeview
        self.treeview.delete(*self.treeview.get_children())

        # Iterate through each category
        for category in categories:
            category_name = category[0]

            # Insert category as parent item
            parent_item = self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=category_name)

            # Fetch items belonging to the current category
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Item=?", (category_name,))
            items = cursor.fetchall()

            # Populate the Treeview with items belonging to the current category
            for item in items:
                self.treeview.insert(parent_item, 'end', values=item)

        # Close the database connection
        conn.close()


    def search_items(self):
        # Get the search query from the entry field
        query = self.search_var.get()

        # Connect to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect("items.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Search for items based on the query
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Item LIKE ? OR SizeNumeric LIKE ? OR Size LIKE ? OR Year LIKE ? OR Price LIKE ? OR Condition LIKE ?", ('%' + query + '%', '%' + query + '%', '%' + query + '%', '%' + query + '%', '%' + query + '%', '%' + query + '%'))
        search_results = cursor.fetchall()

        # Close the database connection
        conn.close()
        # Clear existing items from the Treeview
        self.treeview.delete(*self.treeview.get_children())

        # Populate the Treeview with search results
        for item in search_results:
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', values=item)

     
    def on_item_double_click(self, event):
        selected_item = self.treeview.selection()[0]
        # Retrieve Item ID from the selected item
        item_id = self.treeview.item(selected_item)['values'][0]
        
        # Retrieve the item name for displaying in the messagebox
        item_name = self.treeview.item(selected_item)['values'][1]

        # Display a messagebox confirmation
        response = messagebox.askyesno("Buy Now", "Do you want to buy {item_name}?")

        if response:  # If the user clicks "Yes"
            self.mark_as_sold(item_id)  # Mark the item as sold and remove it from the Treeview

    
    

    def mark_as_sold(self, item_id):
        # Update the Treeview to reflect the change
        selected_item = self.treeview.selection()[0]
        self.treeview.set(selected_item, column='Sold', value='Yes')

        # Remove the item from the Treeview
        self.treeview.delete(selected_item)

    




class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # Initialization...
        master.title("Unisell Main Menu")
        master.configure(bg="white")

        # Set the initial size of the window
        master.geometry("800x600")  # Adjust the size as needed

        # Logo
        logo_label = tk.Label(master, text="Unisell",bg="white",fg="#0047AB", font=("Cambria", 30, "bold"))
        logo_label.pack(pady=10)

        # Log Out Button
        logout_button = tk.Button(master, text="Log Out", font=("Cambria", 12), bg="white", fg="black", command=self.logout)
        logout_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.NW, padx=10, pady=1)

        # Footer Menu
        self.create_footer_menu()

    def create_footer_menu(self):
        footer_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="white")  # Set background color to white
        footer_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)  # Place the footer at the bottom and make it fill horizontally

        Add_item_button = tk.Button(footer_frame, text="Add item", width=20, height=7,pady=15, font=("Cambria", 20), bg="#A7C7E7", fg="white", command=self.show_add_item_window)
        buy_item_button = tk.Button(footer_frame, text="Buy item", width=20, height=7, pady=15, font=("Cambria", 20), bg="#A7C7E7", fg="white", command=self.show_buy_item_window)

        Add_item_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, pady=5)
        buy_item_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, pady=5)

    def show_add_item_window(self):
        add_item_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        add_item_window.title("Add Item window")
        add_item_window.geometry("600x600")

        # Create an instance of the Add_Item class within the Toplevel window
        add_item_form = Add_Item(add_item_window)

    def show_buy_item_window(self):
        buy_item_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        buy_item_window.title("Buy Item window")
        buy_item_window.geometry("600x600")

        # Create an instance of the BuyItemPage class within the Toplevel window
        buy_item_page = BuyItemPage(buy_item_window)

   



        

    def logout(self):
        self.master.destroy()  # Close the main menu window when logging out



    


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = LoginPage(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items This statement won't execute if the table already exists.  I'm guessing that you have an older version of that table, before you added the IsSold column.
